# laravel 5.2 multi auth and laravel localization auth not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I develop site with laravel 5.2 and use

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization and

http://imrealashu.in/code/laravel/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-2-2/

i have followed everything in that link

my routes.php

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 
'middleware' => ['web', 'localize', 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect']
], function () {

    //Route::auth();
    Route::get('login', 'UserAuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('login', 'UserAuthController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'UserAuthController@logout');

    //user
    Route::get('user/dashboard', ['as'=> 'user/dashboard', 'uses' => 'UsersController@index']); 
});

Route::group(
['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    //Admin Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','Admin\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','Admin\Auth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','Admin\Auth\AuthController@logout');

    Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@index');

    Route::resource('admin/administrator', 'Admin\AdminController',['except' => 'show']);
```

UserAuthController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Validator;
use Auth;
use Session;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class UserAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);
        if ($validator->fails()){
          // If validation falis redirect back to login.
          return redirect('login')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }else {
          $userdata = [
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password
              ];
          // doing login.
          if (Auth::guard('user')->validate($userdata)) {
            if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt($userdata)) {
              return redirect('/user/dashboard');
            }
          } 
          else {
            // if any error send back with message.
            Session::flash('error', 'Something went wrong'); 
            return redirect('login');
          }
        }

    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('user')->logout();

        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

UsersController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;

//use Session;

use App\User_Profile;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        session()->put('uid',Auth::guard('user')->user()->id);
        session()->put('username', Auth::guard('user')->user()->username);
        session()->put('email', Auth::guard('user')->user()->email);

        $uid = session()->get('uid');
        $username = session()->get('username');

        $profile = User_Profile::where('user_id', '=', $uid)->first();

        return view('users.index', compact('username', 'profile'));
    }
}
```

Admin\Auth\AuthController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use App\Admin;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{


    protected $redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'admin/login';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }



    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
            return view('auth.authenticate');
        }

        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.register');
    }  
}
```

my kernel.php

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],
        // 'auth' => [
        //     \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        //     \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        //     \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        //     \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        //     \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //     \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        // ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'localize' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
        'localizationRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
        'localeSessionRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
        'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotUser::class,
    ];
}
```

config/auth.php

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ]

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
    | that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
    | table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

I have success in admin logged in and do anything to manage backend

but not in user, everytime logged in when i refresh keep redirect back to login page. it seems $this->middleware('auth') not working.

Can you help me,  where did i miss ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you find solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Be sure to have the forms in your views (the login-form, registration-form, ...) post to the localized url's.

So in your blade-views use:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url(LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale(), '/password/email')) }}">
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The above scripts are alright.

I made a mistake in the view, I placed

```
<a href="{{Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()->logout())}}">Signout</a>
```

logout function in the navigation view.

I have changed the link with usual logout link.

```
<a href="{{url('logout')}}">Signout</a>
```

Now its working.

thanks

Comment: Why the -1 on my suggestion below?? I suggested to check your view and i was right the error was in there. You didn't post your view in your question, so nobody could've known where the error was. And btw, my suggestion solved a lot of problems for me with multiple authentication and localization..

Comment: PS. When logging out like in your example with a non-localized url it's no problem, but still i suggest to prefix all the links with the selected localizationcode. Especially when posting data, for example logindata.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, about the post. I found the solution two days after i post the question, and right now i have a time to update my post